# Menu doesn't work when app is opened from background

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I minimize my Ionic app and open it after sometime, everything works except top left menu button and Android hardware back button.

I am unable to figure out the reason. I have to kill my app and reopen it then it works. Do I need to write any code or I need to do something else?

Below is my `home.html` header code:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="headercolor" style="width:100%;">
    <ion-title *ngIf="!toggled"><span style="color:orange;font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;">Dash</span><span style="color:#5990AE;font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;">board</span></ion-title>

  <button ion-button menuToggle *ngIf="!toggled">
    <ion-icon name="menu" class="icon" style="color: #ffffff;font-size:17px;"></ion-icon>
  </button>

    <ion-searchbar *ngIf="toggled" [showCancelButton]="true" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionCancel)="togglesearch()" (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-buttons end *ngIf="!toggled">

      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="togglesearch()">
        <ion-icon name="search" class="icon" style="font-size:16px;"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console logs?

Comment: its on mobile, i am not testing it on console

Comment: You can see the console logs in Chrome look the Docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/developer-tips/